# Get month name from the query in laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to display the month name from the query but its not printing.

Below is my query:

```
$stats = DB::table('leadsheet')
            ->whereYear('created_at', '>=', $days)
            ->groupBy('month')
            ->orderBy('month', 'ASC')
            ->get([
                DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) as month'),
                DB::raw('COUNT(*) as value')
            ]);
```

And my json data is coming like below :

```
[{"month":1,"value":380},{"month":2,"value":2146},{"month":3,"value":2008},{"month":4,"value":1399},{"month":5,"value":1719},{"month":6,"value":4497},{"month":7,"value":911},{"month":8,"value":495},{"month":9,"value":691},{"month":10,"value":370},{"month":11,"value":479}]
```

In this result , i just want to display instead numbers  1 as Jan ,2 as Feb and so on ..but i was trying to give the format for month its not happening.

desired input like as:

```
{"month":Jan,"value":380}...
```

Can anybody help me out ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
CASE MONTH(created_at) WHEN 1 THEN 'JAN'
                       WHEN 2 THEN 'FEB'
                       ...
END as `month`
```

Or, you can use [`MONTHNAME()`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-monthname-function.php) .